# 7Zip fails to uncompress the files created by a JAVA source in Oracle 11g DB

Tags: java, file, oracle11g, compression, 7zip

I've written a JAVA source to zip the files in Oracle DB 11g. The program is working as expected, i.e. it is creating the zip file in the `/home/oracle/` directory. But when I download the files to my hard-disk via FTP or email them using the SMTP server, 7Zip refuses to read the contents of the archive and throws the error:-

> "Unsupported compression method for DAR.xls"

Am I doing something wrong here? Please help.

Code of the JAVA Source is attached:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND RESOLVE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "UTLZip" AS
import java.util.zip.*;
import java.io.*;
public class UTLZip
{
public static void compressFile(String infilename, String outfilename)
{
    String zipFile = "/home/oracle/DAR.zip";

        String[] srcFiles = {"/home/oracle/DAR.xls"};

        try {

            // create byte buffer
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);

            ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

            for (int i=0; i < srcFiles.length; i++) {

                File srcFile = new File(srcFiles[i]);

                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(srcFile);


                zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(srcFile.getName()));

                int length;

                while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    zos.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }

                zos.closeEntry();

                // close the InputStream
                fis.close();

            }

            // close the ZipOutputStream
            zos.close();

        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Error creating zip file: " + ioe);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you can decompress the file you have just written, without downloading it.  You should be able to run and tests this on your PC>

Answer (score 0):

As @peter-lawrey wrote, first check if the zip archive is valid if you uncompress it from the **/home/oracle/**.
If it is, maybe you have to check if the transfert between your server and your PC didn't corrupt the file (For example, if you tranfered the zip file using *ftp* protocole, be aware of the data-type used while transfering)

Comment: Thank you @LouMéou and Peter for your comments. As suggested, I unzipped the file created at /home/oracle/ by coding a JAVA source called UTLUnZip in Oracle DB 11g. Upon execution of this JAVA source, DAR.xls got created in /home/oracle/ directory. I FTPed this file and it opens perfectly on my PC. Now the big question is how do I get the ZIP file to open on my PC? I need to send the ZIP file as an email attachment to my users from Oracle DB itself (using a scheduled job). Pls help.

Comment: Maybe you should take care of the mime-type used while transfering the zip file. This should be a _binary_ type, this is where I will look first.

Comment: Tried with the octet stream and zip stream but to no avail :'(